# How to call requestConnectionPriority correctly in FMX for Andoid BLE?

Tags: java, android, delphi, bluetooth-lowenergy, firemonkey

I can't get `requestConnectionPriority` called correctly in Delphi Alexandria 11.3 FMX for Andoid BLE?

I actually assumed that the following code is sufficient to get the `requestConnectionPriority`.
`Androidapi.JNI.Bluetooth` is included in uses and declared in `Androidapi.JNI.Bluetooth.pas` like this:

```
TJBluetoothGatt = class(TJavaGenericImport<JBluetoothGattClass, JBluetoothGatt>) end;
```

Now here is my code:

```
var
  JBluetoothGatt: TJBluetoothGatt; // requestConnectionPriority added in API level 21
begin
  JBluetoothGatt.Create;
 
 JBluetoothGatt.Wrap(self).requestConnectionPriority(JBluetoothGatt.JavaClass.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH); // this is nonsense but all function calls are visible, why ????
  JBluetoothGatt.Free;
end;
```

I would have expected more of a function like this now:

```
JBluetoothGatt.requestConnectionPriority(CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

JBluetoothGatt has no functions. Only wrap lets me access the functions (list).
I have no idea what AJINIObjectID or IJavaInstance is supposed to be, with is to call Wrap.

Anyway, I'm sure it is to act completely different. What is the right way?

Comment: You don't actually create an instance of `TJBluetoothGatt` (which you're doing wrong anyway) - an instance of `JBluetoothGatt` is returned when you call `connectGatt` on an instance of `JBluetoothDevice`. I expect you would call `requestConnectionPriority` once you've done that. It might help you understand how it works by looking at the `System.Android.Bluetooth` unit

Comment: Also, the call would look like this: `requestConnectionPriority(TJBluetoothGatt.JavaClass.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_HIGH)` (you are missing a T). It's not nonsense - it's how the Java bridge works

Comment: Hello Dave,
Thanks for your help.
But I'm afraid it's not enough. Unfortunately, the FMX is completely new material for me. 
I tried to call requestConnectionPriority() after the device is connected and the notification is switched on.

like this:
ADevice is the connected device. 

const ADevice: TBluetoothLEDevice

TJBluetoothGatt.Wrap(ADevice).requestConnectionPriority(TJBluetoothGatt.JavaClass.CONNECTION_PRIORITY_LOW) ;

Unfortunately, my calls are aborted with an error. Maybe you can show me the complete functioncall.

Comment: The code in your comment is incorrect, since `TBluetoothLEDevice` is a Delphi class, and you cannot use `TJBluetoothGatt.Wrap` with it, not to mention that it does not even make sense. As per my earlier comment: an instance of `JBluetoothGatt` is returned when you call `connectGatt` on an instance of `JBluetoothDevice`. If all this is new, that is why I suggested looking at the Delphi source to learn from it.